# How to fix "SDL_image could not initialize!"?

Tags: c++, dll, compiler-errors, windows-10, 32bit-64bit

I'm following a tutorial on how to do SDL2 programming in C++. I'm on windows. My computer is 64 bit. I'm using 32 bit libraries for compatibility reasons and because I'm following a tutorial [which has instructed to use 32 bit versions].

I tried to call the SDL image library with my compiler, and got the following error:

"SDL_image could not initialize! SDL_image Error: Failed loading libpng16-16.dll: The specified procedure could not be found"

(I put all of the Dlls I could find into MySysWow64 I've never been good at linking up compilers so I probably did that wrong [I'm using codeblocks])

It also produces the following pop-up:

"SDL Tutorial: SDL2_TEST1.exe - Entry Point Not Found

The procedure entry point inflateValidate could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\windows\SYSTEM32\libpng16-16.dll"

The tutorial instructed me to place the DLLs for SDL image into the MySysWow64 directory; I thought I did that. What could be causing this and how I can I troubleshoot in order to fix it?

PS: I'm using windows10, not sure if that's relevant, but since it may be, this is why I included it; I assumed that was a good idea, if not, I am totally flexible on this. I wanna ask only the best questions

Comment: Hi, it is a long time that I am not using SDL, but it looks to be, based on past experiences, that you might nothave initialized the SDL engine. Please have a look to this https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Init I hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Will do, I've been at learning it for a while but stuff always got in the way

Comment: I will have to double check the code tomorrow (I'm checking my phone in bed right now)

Comment: +Maurizio Benedetti , am about to check code, am on schedule (or atleast stackexchange says I said "tommorrow" yesterday)

Comment: Umm of note: I emailed the person who made the tutorials: my error; and they said it was a "Linker Error" and that I didn't even need source code. (Because I was emailing them for permission to put their "DO NOT REPRODUCE WITHOUT PRIOR PERMISSION FROM THE AUTHOR" source code here on stack exchange to help with the error debugging)

Comment: No, in his code he has a "bool init()" which contains "SDL_Init" in it. Thanks for the suggestion though, do you know of anything else it could be? If it is a Linker Error (as it probably is since the tutorial person said so), how would/what is the proper for for linking, I feel like such an amature (I kindof am on one hand but on the other hand I've been doing this afterschool since middle school and I graduated last year so I need to step it up)

Comment: So I think we shouldfocus on this: ... "SDL Tutorial: SDL2_TEST1.exe - Entry Point Not Found

The procedure entry point inflateValidate could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\windows\SYSTEM32\libpng16-16.dll"

 ... what is it trying to tell me? And what does that mean in my case? Cos if I knew that: I get the feeling this could solve itself

Comment: @Maurizio Benedetti I forgot whether it's "@" or "+", but, I added details. They may be pertinent, you're like the only person who saw this it seems so sorry for treating you like my last hope on this [you kinda are]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit the same error with SDL after unpacking zlib1.dll (version 1.2.8) from SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.14 to my compiler's bin folder, much like unpacking to your MySysWow64 folder which I'd be much less inclined to do. Searching the error "The procedure entry point inflateValidate" will pull up lots of zlib1.dll conflict results. The zlib1.dll (1.2.11) from SDL2_image-devel-2.0.4 worked where the 1.2.8 version generated the error you report. Delete zlib1.dll and find a newer version, also consider that there may be another conflicting zlib1.dll already in your PATH somewhere else which is causing the error, check your PATH for other copies of the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by updating the order of entries of PATH. The error messages were implying that I have multiple versions of these files. I've reordered the PATH values so that the SDL and SDL_image libraries were the first two entries and that did the trick for me.